# One input text field with two submit buttons, searching separate pages

Tags: php, url, isset

I have a project that requires a search form that searches two separate eBay stores depending on what the user is looking for.

I want to have one input field with two submit buttons. I'm having problems getting the form to specify which site to call from either of the buttons. I've had a good look around and tried a few things but thought someone might be able to straighten out my syntax etc.

I have the form.

```
<form target="_blank" action="rp.php" method="get">

<input type="text">

<button name="replacement" type="submit">Search Replacement Parts</button>

<button name="performance" type="submit">Search Performance Parts</button>

</form>
```

..and I have the PHP.

```
<?php

    if( isset($_GET['replacement']) ) {

        header("Location: http://www.example.com");
        exit;

    } else if {

        ( isset($_GET['performance']) ) {

        header("Location: http://www.example.com");
        exit;

    }

?>
```

I think I'm on the right track, just need a bit-o-help. I don't know whether or not to use POST or GET, GET seemed to make more sense to me for this.

Comment: From your question it is difficult to guess your exact requirement can you please explain further?

Comment: can't use POST. Your header() redirects will be transformed into GET requests, losing the POST form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code for this:

```
<form target="_blank" name="myform"  method="POST">

<input type="text" name="search">

<button  onclick="submit1('http://example1.com/')" >Search Replacement Parts</button>

<button onclick="submit1('http://example2.com/')" >Search Performance Parts</button>

</form>

<script>

   function submit1(url)
   {
      document.myform.action=url;
      document.myform.submit();
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, Vikas /Peter - this worked best for my scenario, cheers guys. D

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is a bit off for the `elseif`, otherwise it should "work"

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['replacement']) ) {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    exit;
} elseif ( isset($_GET['performance']) ) {
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    exit;
}
?>
```

You can use either a `GET` or a `POST` to do this, however a `GET` will result in the query values being visible in the querystring and are limited in size in some older browsers. `POST` is probably prefered, in which case you would replace `$_GET` with `$_POST` in the code above, and change `method="get"` to `method="post"` in your form.

Comment: also need to define form post method as `post`

Answer (score 0):

I would use same name for both buttons, with different value for each one and then in php code just check which value is submitted.